# Why is the code outputing a zero as the highest negative number?

Tags: c#

In the code I want to get the highest negative number but `maxNegative` never even gets set. Why is that?

```cs
int number;
int? maxNegative = null;
bool foundNegative = false;

do
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (number <= -1)
    {
        foundNegative = true;

        if ( number <= -1 && number > maxNegative)
        {
            maxNegative = number;
        }
    }
} while (number != 0);

if (foundNegative)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The maximum negative number is: " + maxNegative);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("jh");
}
```

I tried making it `< 0` and also `<= -1`. Also I tried and made it the lowest negative number and it worked fine.

Comment: There's not much point in re-evaluating `number <= -1` inside the inner if statement.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to find the smallest negative number or the highest negative number? Can you give an example with input values and how you think the code should evaluate them? Also, you shouldn't declare `maxNegative` as nullable, instead it should hold the smallest possible value.

Comment: @ewerspej the input is 1, -3, 7, -6, -2 and the expected output is -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but maxNegative never even gets set

That's because you have this in your inner if statement

```
number > maxNegative
```

`maxNegative` is null. A number cannot be greater than null. Nor can a number be less than or equal to null. These will always evaluate to `false`.

This causes the inner if statement to never execute, thus `maxNegative` never gets changed from its initial `null` value.

---

Let's do some cleanup of the code.

You don't need the `foundNegative` variable. You already know if a negative was found based on `maxNegative` itself - if `maxNegative` is null you didn't find a negative. If `maxNegative` is not null you did find a negative.

Now, the if statements.

The outer if statement checks if the number is negative. That one's fine. The inner if statement we want to change around.

The first thing to do is if `maxNegative` is null, we should just blindly overwrite it with the input `number`. Because of the outer if statement we already know that `number` will be negative, and because `maxNegative` is null, this is the first negative we've found, so it's automatically the largest.

If, however, `maxNegative` is *not* null, then you should evaluate if `number` is larger or not.

These two cases can be combined in one if statement with an OR.

```
int? maxNegative = null;
int number;

do
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (number <= -1)
    {
        if (maxNegative is null || number > maxNegative)
        {
            maxNegative = number;
        }
    }
} while (number != 0);

if (maxNegative is not null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The maximum negative number is: " + maxNegative);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No negative numbers inputted");
}
```